# Sorted Array/Map Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sorting, nscoding

I performed a GET request, and I saved data inside ***data*** like this

```
if let data: [MyMap] = response?.results {
   let var_to_sort = data
   self.generateStuff(var: var_to_sort)
}
```

MyMap is a mappable object defined like this:

```
class MyMap: NSCoding {
   var name: String?
   var score: Score?
   ...
```

With mapping, encode etc ...
Score is the same as the one above:

```
class Score:NSCoding {
   var number: Double?
   ...
```

What I need is to sort ***var_to_sort = data*** based on number (from greatest to leasts) and pass it to the ***generateStuff*** method. Remember that response.results has more than 1 object. Someone can help me?

Comment: What have you tried, have you read documentation for `Array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply sort your array:

```
let var_to_sort = data.sorted {
  $0.score?.number ?? 0 > $1.score?.number ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have a working solution for your need. And possibly a way to improve your code by trying to avoid optionals when there's no need for it. If you're webservice will always return a name and score for your object then don't use optionals, this will make your life easier. You can see in my solution when I don't have any optional that the code is way easier to read and operation like that are trivial.

```
// -------------- Solution 1 avoiding optionals ----------------

struct MyObject {
    var name: String
    var score: Score
}

struct Score {
    var number: Double
}

let data: [MyObject] = [MyObject(name: "obj1", score: Score(number: 12)),
                        MyObject(name: "obj2", score: Score(number: 2)),
                        MyObject(name: "obj3", score: Score(number: 24)),
                        MyObject(name: "obj4", score: Score(number: 4)),
                        MyObject(name: "obj5", score: Score(number: 1))]

let sortedObj = data.sorted(by: { $0.score.number > $1.score.number })
print(sortedObj)
// Print: obj3, obj1, obj4, obj2 and obj5

// -------------- Solution 2 using optionals ----------------

struct MyObject2 {
    var name: String?
    var score: Score2?
}

struct Score2 {
    var number: Double?
}

let data2: [MyObject2] = [MyObject2(name: "obj1", score: Score2(number: 12)),
                          MyObject2(name: "obj2", score: Score2(number: 2)),
                          MyObject2(name: "obj3", score: Score2(number: 24)),
                          MyObject2(name: "obj4", score: Score2(number: 4)),
                          MyObject2(name: "obj5", score: Score2(number: 1))]

let sortedObj2 = data2.sorted(by: {
    guard let num1 = $0.score?.number, let num2 = $1.score?.number else {
        return false
    }
    return num1 > num2
})
print(sortedObj2)
// Print: obj3, obj1, obj4, obj2 and obj5
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array this way.

```
data2.sort(by:{$0.score?.number > $1.score?.number})
```